# SCCM 2012 R2 Deployment Status page Asset Details pane Last Logged On User shows (SYSTEM)

Tags: software-distribution, sccm

This might be a simple answer.
I'm in the middle of troubleshooting why my software update deployment didn't succeed on some clients so I'm looking in SCCM 2012 R2>Monitoring>Deployments>My Deployment at the error tab and in the asset details pane at the bottom, the Last Logged On User shows (SYSTEM) for all the systems.

My User Device Affinity is working because I can go over to my queries and I made a modified version of the Systems by Last Logged On User (took the criteria off basically) and that will show me the last user to log into that machine.

It would be really helpful if, instead of (SYSTEM) it actually showed me the correct user name.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I now updated to SCCM 2012 R2 SP1 and I see that this issue still persists.  If @meatspace is correct and LastLoggedOnUser is the whoever was logged on during the last heartbeat then can I maybe tell it to ignore the (system) user?

Answer (score 0):

`LastLoggedOnUser` is whoever was logged on during the last heartbeat, so it may have not been anyone. Try looking in Asset Intelligence (Hardware 09A - Search for computers) for `TopConsoleUser` instead.

Comment: But how would I get the Asset Details pane in Deployment Status to show TopConsoleUser?